# How to change axis limits and tick step of a MatLab figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a simple plot of `y` against `x`.

```
y = [6,-1.3,-8,-11.7,-11,-6,1.3,8,11.7,11,6,-1.3];
x = 0:0.3:3.3;
plot (x,y)
```

As the result, the x-axis of the figure is ranging from 0 to 3.5, with scale of 0.5. I have used the `XLimit = [0 3.3]` to limit the axis, but it seems like not working.

I wish to make the **x-axis** range from 0 to 3.3 with steps of 0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
axis tight % removes the empty space after 3.3
set(gca,'XTick',0:0.3:3.3) % sets the x axis ticks
```

Comment: Thank you for your great effort!

Answer (score 4):

With `XLimit = [0 3.3]` you just define a vector called `XLimit`. In order to use this vector as horizontal limit, you should use `xlim`:

```
xlim(XLimit)
% or directly:
xlim([0, 3.3])
```

Read more about [`xlim` here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html). Similarly you can set the vertical limit with [`ylim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html).

Since you are trying to set the limits equal to the range of `x`, you will probably find the following command most helpful:

```
axis tight
```

But note that it changes both x- and y-axis limits.

To set the tick step, [as AVK said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928805/6469393), you should `set` the `'XTick'` to `0:0.3:3.3`:

```
set(gca,'XTick',0:0.3:3.3)
```

`gca` is the handle to current axes.